# Compile and execute cpp in xcode, and add additional execution instructions, Such as iconv command

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

Sorry, I'm new to Xcode and not very familiar with it, I use Xcode (command line tool project with external build system) to compile cpp files and automatically execute cpp unix executable files. After the program is compiled (command+R), I set the settings as shown in the screenshot below to automatically execute. Is there any way for me to execute also add additional commands?
Such as iconv.

[image: my scheme settings]

The following line is what I ultimately want to execute.
./myFile argument1 | iconv -f big5

But my Xcode looks like it's executing only
./myFile argument1

really thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same place where you setup the build scheme, you can also add a post-build script.

- Go to the left of the panel, and expand ***Build***
- Select ***Post-actions***
- Near the bottom center, click on <kbd>+</kbd> -> ***New Run Script Action***
- Add script like you would run them in terminal

  - Note the current directory will not be where the project is built
  - You can use `${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}` macro for the build directory
- ***Note***, you want to make sure to select your current project at the ***Provide build settings from*** so it can import the correct path macros like `TARGET_BUILD_DIR`

A screenshot of adding a post-build script:
[image: Screenshot of adding a post-build script]

<sup>*Older versions of Xcode might have different GUI, but the idea should be about the same.</sup>

---

- Sidenote, <kbd>⌘R</kbd> is really for running the program within Xcode, consider using <kbd>⌘B</kbd>.